# Image Button have to place right and left corner

Tags: android, android-xml

I have to place the image to left and right corner with two arrows.But it is placing near to the centre.

I used linearlayout for both arrows and set the orientation to horizontal.I have posted the codes and screenshot below:

**activity_arrow.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relative"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linear"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/rightArrow"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight=".01"
            android:background="@null"
            android:paddingLeft="50dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/left_arrow"
            />


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/leftArrow"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_weight=".01"
            android:background="@null"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/right_arrow" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: LinearLayout gravity is center
why don't you use Relative layout and align parent left and align parent right for both ImageButton

Comment: try removing this android:gravity="center" from your LinearLayout

Comment: @CodeProcessor removed that one

Comment: Do not use RelativeLayout near the root of the view hierarchy, its very expensive solution. Check my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this it will perfect as per your requirment,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relative"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linear"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/rightArrow"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight=".01"
            android:background="@null"
            android:paddingLeft="50dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/left_arrow"
            />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/leftArrow"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_weight=".01"
            android:background="@null"
            android:padding="5dp"
             android:drawableRight="@drawable/right_arrow" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]
Hope this will be helpful...thanks

Comment: just now tried this one.perfect using linearlayout.Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You should use [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html)

[android:layout_alignParentBottom](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android%3Alayout_alignParentBottom) to move the layout to the bottom of the screen.after that align images inside RelativeLayout by using align right and align left.use marging left and marging right for spacing.

Comment: If I use relative layout for imagebutton,views wouldn't appear.

Comment: it due to the use of fill_parent for the parent view_group.try to use layout_weight property

Answer (score 1):

try like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_above="@+id/filter_check2"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/filter_check2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/right_arrow"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/filter_check"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/left_arrow"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Output:-**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

`

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/rightArrow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/leftArrow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</LinearLayout>
```

`

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/abc_btn_check_material"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/leftArrow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/left_arrow"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/rightArrow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/right_arrow"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use Relative layout at the top of view hiearchy. Its expensive as it is a two phase layout. Android UI framework engineers have many times discouraged its use. Here is a recent post by Chet Hasse https://medium.com/google-developers/developing-for-android-iii-2efc140167fd

As he writes

> it is important to understand that RelativeLayout is an expensive
>   solution, because it requires two measurement passes to ensure that it
>   has handled all of the layout relationships correctly.

LinearLayout with weight is also a two phase layout. We should use RelativeLayout and LinearLayout with weight only if there is no better way.

Instead of using RelativeLayout in the root use Framelayout similar to this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/imageViewContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="48dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

</FrameLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/rightArrow"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight=".01"
        android:background="@null"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/left_arrow"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:paddingLeft="48dp"
        />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/leftArrow"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_weight=".01"
        android:background="@null"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/right_arrow"
        android:padding="4dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you.This too helpful to me.